# Skinning algorithms

Tags: 3d, interpolation, skinning

Skeletal animation is a well-known techniques in 3D Computer Graphics. I am interested in transformation blending algorithm when a final transformation is calculated from several join transformations. I read about different techniques and I have tried dual quaternion and linear matrix methods. I understand that first gives good results and the second has problems. However, I don't understand why it cannot be split a transformation into translation and rotation and make their interpolations separately. For example, I can present the rotation as Euler angles (with some restrictions) and the translation as vector and make a linear interpolation. What are the problems with this method of interpolation? Why do all people (in papers, posts, ...) suggest to use complex and performance consuming methods?

Comment: Read Kavan's original papers about dual quaternion skinning, he explains pretty well why interpolating translation and rotation seperately gives problems. And besides that, **never ever**, again **never ever** use Euler angles for interpolation between different rotations. In fact Euler angles have only very few use cases where they really make sense, but interpolation is **the** anti-use-case.

Comment: And as to performance, dual quaternion skinning isn't really slower than interpolating and applying translation and rotation (as a quaternion) seperately (when done correctly, you don't do a quaternion-to-matrix-conversion inside a shader, of course), and it isn't much more complex either, once you understood screw transformations and built the basic conversion routines.

Comment: Thx. Can u, please, make an answer and support "the anti-use-case" by some links with explanation?

Comment: Besides all that, the question doesn't fit well on StackOverflow, due to its broadness and generality. Maybe the guys at [gamedev.se](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) are more of help to you.